# Change background color when radio is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the background color of a block when a radio button , which is inner the block, is clicked.

I did this but I don't understand why it dont work.
Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rad').click(function() {
        $('#label').addClass('radio-active');
    });
});
```

```css
.radio-active {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="radio-item" id="label">
      <input id="rad" type="radio" name="rad" >
      <label class="radio-label"for="f-option">£25</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thx

Comment: Put your class in a style tag or a css file.Make sure you included Jquery.

Comment: I changed your code block to snippet. It looks like everything there works perfect. Did you remember to include the `jquery` lib?

Comment: @cjl750 the `li` element has that label

Comment: it works, do not forget to link the jQuery library : https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: You can actualy do this just by using CSS. What are your browsers ?

Comment: Thank you @G-Cyr & Dekel I was missing the jquery link. To other thank you for your attention and your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, it sounds as though you may have forgotten to wrap the CSS in `<style>` tags.

I've rewritten your jQuery into vanilla JS - since it's a relatively simple task you're trying to achieve, why not go vanilla? :-)

```js
document.querySelector("#rad").addEventListener("change", function() {
    var label = document.getElementById("label");
    label.classList.add("radio-active");
});
```

```css
.radio-active {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="radio-item" id="label">
      <input id="rad" type="radio" name="rad" >
      <label class="radio-label"for="f-option">£25</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put this css code:

```
.radio-active {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

with in `style` tag like:

```
<style>
.radio-active {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you were missing the `<style>` tags around your CSS class. Because your code is working:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#rad').click(function() {
    $('#label').addClass('radio-active');
  });
});
```

```css
.radio-active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="radio-item" id="label">
    <input id="rad" type="radio" name="rad" >
    <label class="radio-label"for="f-option">£25</label>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

It perfectly works here...

Are you calling the jQuery correctly?

```
<style>
.radio-active {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rad').click(function() {
        $('#label').addClass('radio-active');
    });
});
</script>

<ul>


<li class="radio-item" id="label">
    <input id="rad" type="radio" name="rad" >
    <label class="radio-label"for="f-option">£25</label>
</li>

<li class="2radio-item" id="label2">
    <input id="rad2" type="radio" name="rad2" >
    <label class="radio-label2"for="f-option2">£35</label>
</li>

</ul>
```

[image uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/il1Wc.png)